# AngularJS $http put request not calling Django view function

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have a click button which should pass some parameters from the front end to a django view function.

However when I use $http.put my code does not go into the django "action" view function.

When I use $http.get then the action view function is accessed, however I need to use $http.put to pass front end data - why would it not access the action view def?

```
<tr ng-repeat="Script in Scripts | filter :{timestamp : datefilter}  | orderBy:column:reverse ">
    <td>{{ Script.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ Script.script }}</td>
    <td>{{ Script.timestamp }}</td>
    <td>{{ Script.hostname }}</td>
    <td>{{ Script.subject }}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'red':Script.status =='= ISSUE =','green':Script.status == '= OK ='}">{{ Script.status }}</td>
    <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="actionFun(Script)"></button></td>
</tr>
```

Controller.js function:

```
$scope.actionFun = function(Script){
    var data = JSON.stringify(Script);
    console.log("Output 1: ", data);
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/action/",data).success(function(data, status){
    #$http.put ("http://127.0.0.1:8000/action/",data).success(function(data, status){
        console.log("Output 2: ", data);
    })
};
```

Django View Code:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def action(request):
    import paramiko
    print("Im here")
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        data = request.data
        print(data.get('location'))
        *** Do Some Function ***
```

Comment: There is no HTTP verb "push". Did you mean "put"?

Comment: I have tried the same with Put - Also doesn't go into def action(request)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include 'PUT' ver in your api_view decorator parameters:

`@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])`

This list is checked in first place, so if api gets method with signature that it's not on the list request is not matched with the method and cannot execute the code.

Comment: I have added @api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE']) but still it is not working

Comment: Interestingly im seeing the following on the Rest API viewset: 

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

Comment: I am seeing: "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/action/ 403 (Forbidden)" in the console logs